# Angular: ng-repeat filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<label disabled>Buscar: 
        <input ng-model="searchText.descripcion" placeholder="search"></input>
    </label>
    <select name="producto" ng-model="producto" >
        <option ng-repeat="p in productos | filter:searchText" value="{{p}}">{{p.descripcion}}</option>
    </select>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El filtro funciona correctamente, lo que necesito es que el Search sea el primer campo del option ng-repeat y que vaya filtrando y mostrándome los que coinciden con la descripción.

Answer (score -1):

Claro ahí te modificaron el filter donde agregas con el después del search con un punto donde querés realizar la búsqueda, si lo colocas como al principio buscaba en todos los campos.

Comment: podrias mirar [answer] y aclarar esta respuesta?